# How can i convert my if and else-if statements into a switch case?

Tags: java, switch-statement, joptionpane

I've recently started learning Java. My teacher has given us this homework assignment which is about writing and converting the If-Else statement code below into a Switch-Case statement code. I wrote the If-Else statement code correctly but i haven't been able to convert my if and else-if to a switch case statements. The sooner I can get an answer the better. Thank you.

ive tried adding a switch and then changing each number to case 1, case 2,etc.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ExerciseV {
  public static void main(String [] args){

 String rating;
    String performance;

     rating = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your rating for the gymnast from (1-10)?");

     if(rating.equalsIgnoreCase("One")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("one")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("1")||
        rating.equals("Two")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("two")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("2")||
        rating.equals("Three")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("three")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
     System.out.println("You scored the performance a rating of: " + rating);
          performance = "BAD";
     System.out.println("You typed in the number "+ rating +" so they had a "+ performance +" performance.");
     }
     else if(rating.equals("Four")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("four")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("4")||
             rating.equals("Five")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("five")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("5")||
        rating.equals("Six")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("six")||rating.equalsIgnoreCase("6")){
     System.out.println("You scored the performance a rating of: " + rating);
          performance = "AVERAGE";
     System.out.println("You typed in the number "+rating+" so they had a "+performance+" performance.");
     }
```

all this is correct but i just dont know where and how to put the switch cases into this program.

Comment: As an aside: `rating.equalsIgnoreCase("one")` is reundant following `rating.equalsIgnoreCase("One")`.

Comment: "The sooner I can get an answer the better" [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3788176)

Comment: i like its due today in 2 hours. really sorry for the late notice i just got stuck with this part

Comment: ah okay thank you andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code could help you

```
switch(rating.toUpperCase()) { 
        case "ONE":
        case "1":
        case "TWO":
        case "2":
            performance = "BAD";
            break;

        case "THREE":
        case "3":
        //...
    }
```

Now, adapt this type of solution to your real problem